# How to access json muliple data

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

I want to ask how can I access to my multiple data in jquery (json response).
Here's how my data looks like:
[image]

How can I display all kid's names?

```
$.ajax({
  ...
}).done(function(kids){
  console.log(kids);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the call is:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
}).done(function(data){
    // code here
});
```

You can loop through if you want to work on one item at a time.

```
for (var i in data.kids) {
  console.log(data.kids[i].name)
}
```

If you want to extract all the names, you can use jquery .map, eg:

```
var names = $(data.kids).map(function(i,e) { return e.name }).get();
console.dir(names)
```

then you can show them all in one go:

```
console.log(names.join(", "))
```

Here's a fiddle, with console output:  https://jsfiddle.net/cvre71dr

Answer (score 1):

Do you know loops?

```
$.each(kids.kids,function(i,v){
  console.log(v.name);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know but it's returning undefined

Comment: You need to use `$.each(kids.kids)` because the kids array is a property of your returned data that you've called kids.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

```js
var json = {kids : [{name:'Kid1'},{name:'Kid2'},{name:'Kid3'},{name:'Kid4'},{name:'Kid5'}]}


for(x=0;x<json.kids.length;x++){
  
document.write(json.kids[x].name);
  }
```

Comment: Your's solution is also returning undefined

Comment: Could you please provide the json..?

Comment: The json is in the question (though as an image...)